# Работа с AsyncTask в Android Json

Tags: java, json, android-asynctask

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста в чем моя ошибка уже сутки ломаю голову над проблемой. Создал проект в котором происходит парсинг json с внешнего ресурса. Проблема заключается в том что как код заканчивает свою работу происходит выход из приложения.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ocean_shop.jp.MainActivity">

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/message"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ocean_shop.jp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"></uses-feature>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.ocean_shop.jp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";

    private TextView mTextView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);

        new ParseTask().execute();
    }

    private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";

        String base64EncodedCredentials;
        String Username = "MYUSER";
        String Password = "MYPASS";


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mTextView.setText("Загрузка");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса

            try {
                //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString((Username + ":" + Password).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);


                URL url = new URL("http://MYSERVER/ocean_shop/odata/standard.odata/AccumulationRegister_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8/Turnovers(StartPeriod=datetime'2018-02-06',%20EndPeriod=datetime'2018-02-07')?$format=json;odata=nometadata");



                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
                // urlConnection.setReadTimeout(2500);
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);
            // выводим целиком полученную json-строку

            JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;

            try {
                dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);

                JSONArray value = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("value");

                int СтоимостьTurnover = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject values = value.getJSONObject(i);

                    СтоимостьTurnover = СтоимостьTurnover + values.getInt("СтоимостьTurnover");

                   // Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Стоимость: " + СтоимостьTurnover);




                }
//В логи выводиться
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Стоимость: " + СтоимостьTurnover);
// При попытки вывести на экран приложение останавливаеться
                mTextView.setText(СтоимостьTurnover);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.ocean_shop.jp, PID: 7308
                  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x8d5e
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331)
                      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4554)
                      at com.ocean_shop.jp.MainActivity$ParseTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:139)
                      at com.ocean_shop.jp.MainActivity$ParseTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:39)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

В место MYUSER,MYPASS,SERVER стоят мои значения

Answer (score 1):

Нашел в чем проблема. Я пытался строковому значению передать число. решил так

```
mTextView.setText(Integer.toString(СтоимостьTurnover));
```